# 98 Saturn SL2 Starter and Water Pump Will Not Work

Tags: starting, saturn, sl2

I just put in new radiator and sometimes the car will start, but not lately. It is also heating up quickly. I think that both the starter and water pump are not working due to some sensor or fuse they both use together.

***I don't know what could be wrong, any suggestions?***

Thank you.

Comment: What do you see and hear when you try to start?

Comment: Did the lack of starting occur before you put in the new radiator?

Comment: The water pump is electric? That seems kind of odd. a GM 1.9 uses a mechanical belt driven pump I thought.

Comment: all inside electrical starts and stays on. no sound when switch to start is  turned.and yes had same no start situation before radiator was put in. Now, i can push car and start by popping clutch but 20 30 min later water boiling out of overflow wich makes me think water pump not circulating water.When  car rarely starts though no boiling of water coming from overflow and temp normal.

Comment: also checked battery no problem there

Comment: sorry also checked neutral safety switch and its working .

Answer (score 1):

For the no start you'll need to check wiring to the starter. You may or may not have an anti-theft module in your car. Is there a flashing security light when the key is in the on position? Is the battery fully charged?

Here's how I would test the circuit, locate the starter relay. In your case it would be under the driver side dash. Pull the relay noting the position it came out, it's a 4 pin relay with a diagram on it. There should be always hot battery voltage on pin 30, key on ignition voltage on pin 86, ground on pin 87 - this is the pin that goes to the neutral safety switch, pin 85 is the relay coil ground, this is either controlled by the anti theft system or is always grounded. Note 85/86 may be reversed.

Is the circuit to this point OK? Does the relay click when turning the key? Assuming the relay is good, try jumping power from pin 30 to 87 does the engine turn over? If not check the neutral safety switch next. Is the car in park/neutral/clutch switch closed? having someone help you, check voltage in and out of the neutral safety switch. In the case of an AT car both wires are purple. For an MT it's yellow in purple out.

If everything to this point checks out look at the wiring on the starter solenoid. the small S terminal is the wire from the neutral safety switch. The 4 gauge cable is battery to starter and should always have battery voltage. If everything is OK try tapping it with a hammer. At this point though it's probably a safe bet to replace the starter.

As to your temperature gauge make sure the coolant is full. Make sure that your serpentine belt is in good shape. Has the engine over heated before? with the engine up to temperature check for bubbling in the coolant overflow/reservoir. If it is consistently blowing bubbles you have a bad head gasket. How about your thermostat? has it ever been replaced? is it stuck closed? At operating temperature both hoses should be roughly the same temperature. If one is hot the other cold the thermostat may be stuck closed. In which case you would want to remove and test it.

On an SL2 the instrument cluster receives coolant temp info from the pcm which receives voltage from the coolant temp sensor. A 2 wire signal/low reference connector. Both coming from the pcm.

Comment: I would suggest with the recent change of radiator, the cooling system may not have been bled correctly. Also wondering if the radiator cap was put on correctly to prevent overflow. OP never really states if the engine was overheating or if there was just coolant bubbling out of the overflow. Could be a weak radiator cap not providing the proper amount of pressure to the system